# Connect to Database when file is moved onto Remote Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have created a Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET Web Application. With it I have used a .MDF database file in which the membership services has generated the necessary tables and stored procedures etc. . . .

the connectionstring is as follows

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PIPEFIXX.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

now thats on the remote server after I have finished testing, just using a straight FTP (FileZilla), no publishing of any kind using Visual Studio. It won't now connect to that database. I know that the path is

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/App_Data/
```

as that is what has been uploaded.

Any Suggestions

Comment: What error does it get when trying to connect?

Comment: Does your remote hosting have sql express installed?  You are specifying a database instance at .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Have you checked if the instance is named ".\SQLEXPRESS" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the data source is, it says "Server ATLAS-SQL-07" that is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a permissions issue? The effective identity for your app (could be the anonymous user, IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool, or whatever you have it set to) needs to be able to read/write the App_Data folder on the remote web site.

Comment: I've made the changes, now waiting for the publish to finish